# Win server 2008 partition security

Tags: bitlocker

I am trying to lock a partition in the server so, that it is accessible by only one domain admin, and not even the administrator can open it. But at the same time I want to keep it shared so, that the the approved domain admin can open it over the network.

I tried folder lock, Bit-locker and Mini Tool Partition Wizard, but couldn't lock it, because once I lock the partition, I cannot access it on the shared network.

How to find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

In principle you can remove domain admins from the local admins group for that server (and put the one blessed admin back).

However, you are not supposed to do this, and goodness knows what you will break. And if something does break, the domain admins can't help you fix it.

If you don't trust your domain admins then you have bigger problems!